# How to identity button and click on it in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

HTML code

```
<input>
<title>Page Title</title>
```

## This is a Heading

This is a paragraph.

```
</input>
```

Not able to identify a button for the above html code in java

Comment: findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@type='button' and @value='Filter')]")).click()

Comment: What does the entire HTML code look like for that element?

Comment: This is the completed html

Comment: Then you have an error in your html code - and that is probably why it is not able to identify it.

Comment: <input class="jmesa_button" type="button" title="filter" value="Filter"
onclick="javascript:onInvokeAction('promotionDefinitionsTable','filter')"></input>

Comment: When you say not able to identify - do you get no such element exception? what is the exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
findElement(By.cssSelector(".jmesa_button[value='Filter']");
```

or

```
findElement(By.cssSelector(".jmesa_button[value='Filter'][title='filter']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Filter']")).click();
```

Comment: Could you please provide some context and not just code? Thanks.